# Postgres: Update Boolean column with false if column contains null

Tags: postgresql, boolean, sql-null

I have existing table called test with two columns id and utilized

Here utilized contains three values in my table null, false and true. Here null is default for utilized

I want to update the rows with utilized false where utilized is null so I tried below query in Postgres but it didn’t work for me.

```
  update test set utilized=false where utilized=null;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must use `IS NULL` to check for the presence of a `NULL` value:

```
UPDATE test
SET utilized = false
WHERE utilized IS NULL;
```

In SQL, unlike other places such as Java or C#, `NULL` is a special value meaning something like "not known."  Therefore, comparing a column to `NULL` using the `=` operator is also unknown, because it might or might not be true.  Instead, use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to directly compare a column to `NULL`.